# Override delete model in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have question model and also have Like and Dislike model, i want that if user have already liked this question and then click like button, delete Like object and question point increase by one.

**example**: question has 10 like --> i send like, so question has 11 like --> i also send like, so delete object and question's like quantity (10)

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("user"))
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name=_("question"))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.question.point += 1
            self.question.save()
        return super(Like, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


@receiver(post_delete, sender=Like)
def delete_like(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    print(instance.question.point) #point is 3
    instance.question.point -= 1
    print(instance.question.point) #point is 2
```

when i print everything is fine but when i open database, result is not same

**edit**:

```
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        like_exist=bool(Like.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()))
        dislike_exist=bool(DisLike.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()))
        self.object=self.get_object()
        context = super(QuestionDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            question = Question.objects.get(id=self.kwargs["pk"])
            context['detail'] = question
            context['like_ex']=like_exist
            context['dislike_ex']=dislike_exist
        except Http404:
            return reverse("Profile:error")

        if "like" or "dislike" in self.request.GET:

            if "like" in self.request.GET:

                    if Like.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()):
                        Like.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()).delete()
                    else:
                        Like.objects.create(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object())
                        if DisLike.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()):
                            DisLike.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()).delete()

            if "dislike" in self.request.GET:

                    if DisLike.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()).exists():
                        DisLike.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()).delete()
                    else:
                        DisLike.objects.create(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object())
                        if Like.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()).exists():
                            Like.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, question=self.get_object()).delete()

        return context
```

Comment: You don't save the `instance.question`...

Comment: Does not work, I think the problem is in the view. I will add and can you see? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i have added

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem oh sorry, i had ```instance.save```, now i change da everything is work!